# Second Run of VBA WordDoc tables add does not set variable

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a VBA routine in Excel which opens a word.app. All the set variables work fine in the multiple runs except for one thing. I hope you can help me out!

The relevant code in my opinion:

```vba
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document

'load format
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:=FormatLocation & FormatFile)

Call MakeTableFields(OHIBSingleEntity, WordDoc)

WordDoc.SaveAs FileName:=SaveFile, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
WordDoc.Close

WordApp.Quit

Set OHIBSingleEntity = Nothing
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set WordApp = Nothing

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub MakeTableFields(EntityFields As Recordset, WordDoc As Word.Document)
'make table sub
Dim PropTbl As Word.Table
Dim RangeCT As Word.Range

    Set RangeCT = WordDoc.Content
    With RangeCT.Find
        .Text = "#InvoegenTabelISB"
        .Format = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Execute
    End With
    
    
    Recordcounter = EntityFields.RecordCount
    
    'Problem is here:
    Set PropTbl = WordDoc.Tables.Add(RangeCT, RoundUp(Recordcounter / 2, 0), 4)

    'after this formatting and filling the just created table with the EntityFields dataset

    Set RangeCT = Nothing
    Set PropTbl = Nothing

End Sub
```

The first run it works as it should. The second time it runs everything works except formatting and filling the table. As far as I can trace it, it looks like `Set PropTbl` does not work. Creating the table works. But the next lines are failing/skipped. When I close the Excel with this VBA and open it again, it again works fine for the first run. Second run fails again.

What I tried was to make the table and then `Set PropTbl`:

```vba
WordDoc.Tables.Add RangeCT, RoundUp(Recordcounter / 2, 0), 4
Set PropTbl = WordDoc.Tables(1)
```

This also gives the same behavior. It almost looks like something is kept in the memory while keeping running excel. But I don't know how to debug the memory while all VBA routines are executed and finished.

Does anybody know how to fix or debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Really wierd, but the fault is not in the posted code

This does work for the first run, but it fails the second time:

```vba
    With PropTbl.Borders
        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
    End With
    With PropTbl.Borders(wdBorderLeft)
        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
    End With
    With PropTbl.Borders(wdBorderBottom)
        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
    End With
    With PropTbl.Borders(wdBorderRight)
        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
    End With
    With PropTbl.Borders(wdBorderVertical)
        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
    End With
    With PropTbl.Borders(wdBorderHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
    End With
```

fix was simple:

`PropTbl.Borders.Enable = True`

Gives the same result. Wierd thing was that it just fails with no error. The only hint I got was from a hover tip over the `Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle` which gives a hint that the servercomputer was not reachable...?

Anyway, it is solved.